# PHP form only shows if user_id is in the database

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a PHP form where the user can either add information or update previous information. 
When Building I entered some information manually into the database to get things working. Now I am find out that the form will not show up for new users because there is no user_id in the database yet.(I tested and manually added the user_ids and the the form then showed up.)

I believe its because my form is wrapped in a while loop.
How can I change my form(INPUTS) to populate if there is no data for the user yet?

```
<?php

$user_id = $_SESSION['User']['logged_in'];
$businessProfileQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sellerBusinessProfile 
WHERE user_id = $user_id;") or die(mysqli_error($db));
while( $row = $businessProfileQuery->fetch_assoc() ) {
       $savedBusinessName = $row['businessName'];
       $$savedBusinessAddress = $row['businessAddress'];
?>
<form>
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="content-header">BUSINESS ADDRESS</p>
            <p class="seller-profile-text"></p>

            <input name="businessName" type="name" class="form-control 
                   seller-input" value="<?php echo $savedBusinessName; ?>">

            <input name="businessAddress" type="name" class="form-control"  
                   value="<?php echo $savedBusinessAddress; ?>" >
        </div>
</form>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: *How can I change my php form to show if there is no data for the user yet*  - can't you put an if before `<div class="form-group row">` that checks for whether `$savedBusinessName` is set or not..?

Comment: You can change while to do-while so that loop will run at-least once..

Comment: Does `sellerBusinessProfile` contain multiple rows per `user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count number of rows.

If number of rows less then or equal 0 then there is no data set for this user.

If number of rows greater then 0 then data already available for this user.

```
                <?php

                $user_id = $_SESSION['User']['logged_in'];
                $businessProfileQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sellerBusinessProfile 
                WHERE user_id = $user_id;") or die(mysqli_error($db));
             if ($businessProfileQuery->num_rows <= 0) {
                ?>
                <form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <p class="content-header">BUSINESS ADDRESS</p>
                            <p class="seller-profile-text"></p>

                            <input name="businessName`enter code here`" type="name" class="form-control 
                                   seller-input" value="">

                            <input name="businessAddress" type="name" class="form-control"  
                                   value="" >
                        </div>
                </form>
                <?php
                 }
                 ?>
```

Comment: Close, fetchColumn() is outdated and my editor will not let me use it. Update your annswer and replace it with fetch_assoc() and I will accept it so others can learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope to help you!

```
<?php

$user_id = $_SESSION['User']['logged_in'];
$businessProfileQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sellerBusinessProfile 
WHERE user_id = $user_id;") or die(mysqli_error($db));
$savedBusinessName = "";
$savedBusinessAddress = "";
while( $row = $businessProfileQuery->fetch_assoc() ) {
       $savedBusinessName = $row['businessName'];
       $savedBusinessAddress = $row['businessAddress'];
}       
?>
<form>
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="content-header">BUSINESS ADDRESS</p>
            <p class="seller-profile-text"></p>

            <input name="businessName" type="name" class="form-control 
                   seller-input" value="<?php echo $savedBusinessName; ?>">

            <input name="businessAddress" type="name" class="form-control"  
                   value="<?php echo $savedBusinessAddress; ?>" >
        </div>
</form>
```